# Possible to have multi-select field in a Gmail Addon?

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail-addons

The [documentation for Cards](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/card-service/) in Gmail Addons only seems to mention basic fields like Text and Select. I was hoping to implement a multi-select / typeahead field but am not sure this is possible.

It's my understanding that only the 'Card' part of that documentation is usable in Gmail, correct?

Has anyone had any experience with this? I'm assuming since it's not in the documentation, it's probably not able to be done.

Answer (score 1):

There is a section in the documentation that might meet your requirements. See link below:

[Autocomplete suggestions for text inputs](https://developers.google.com/gsuite/add-ons/how-tos/suggestions)

Comment: Sadly, this only allows for one field value. I believe I'll have to find a workaround that involves using a typeahead field to add to a list, then have an option to remove items from that list. Thanks for the reply, though!!

Comment: @user161592 Did you manage to find an alternative for multi-select?